# What is the default password and user of the wordpress module installed on easyphp server?

Tags: wordpress, passwords, easyphp

I've dosnloaded   the module of wordpress but I've not found what is the default password on the internet

any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you click a "Generate" button to generate a password? If so, you should have taken a note of the password.

Answer (score 0):

Did you click a "Generate" button to generate a password? If so, you should have taken a note of the password. You could also try the lost password link at

> /wp-login.php?action=lostpassword

Comment: I don't remember if I clicked that button.It is  a module that I dowloaded on the easyphp website, and I installed it.It has already an user and a password, i saw it in the database. When i tried the other solution you gave me,i got this error **The e-mail could not be sent.
Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function.** how can I solve it. thanks